OrderID in master detail doesn't work correctly - in ASP.NET MVC
Please help me with this: when I add new data, it will throw an error

SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__SaleOrde__C3905BAFABA6B181'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SaleOrder'. The duplicate key value is (0).

because the OrderID doesn't get automatically set.
Here it's my code - controller:
using DoAnLTHDT.Models;
using DoAnLTHDT.ViewModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services.Description;

namespace DoAnLTHDT.Controllers
{
    public class MasterDetailController : Controller
    {
        private UserManageEntities objManageEntities;

        public MasterDetailController()
        {
            objManageEntities = new UserManageEntities();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(SaleOrderViewModel objSaleOrderViewModel)
        {
            SaleOrder objSalesOrder = new SaleOrder();
            objSalesOrder.AddressCus = objSaleOrderViewModel.AddressCus;
            objSalesOrder.CustomerName = objSaleOrderViewModel.CustomerName;
            objSalesOrder.OrderNumber = objSaleOrderViewModel.OrderNumber;
            objManageEntities.SaleOrders.Add(objSalesOrder);
            objManageEntities.SaveChanges();

            objSalesOrder = 
                objManageEntities.SaleOrders.Single(model =>
                model.OrderNumber == objSaleOrderViewModel.OrderNumber
            );

            foreach (var item in objSaleOrderViewModel.ListOfSaleOrderDetail)
            {
                SaleOrderDetail objSaleOrderDetail = new SaleOrderDetail();
                objSaleOrderDetail.Discount = item.Discount;
                objSaleOrderDetail.ItemName = item.ItemName;
                objSaleOrderDetail.OrderID = objSalesOrder.OrderID;
                objSaleOrderDetail.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                objSaleOrderDetail.Total = item.SubTotal;
                objSaleOrderDetail.UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice;
                objManageEntities.SaleOrderDetails.Add(objSaleOrderDetail);
                objManageEntities.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Json(data: new {Success = true, Message ="Data Add"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}

Script ajax and jQuery
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnDelete").hide();
    });
    function AddSaleOrderRow() {
        $("#btnDelete").show();
        var tblBody = $("#tblSaleOrderDetails").find("tbody");
        var tblLastRow = tblBody.find("tr:last");
        var tblClone = tblLastRow.clone().find("input[type=text]").val('').end();
        tblLastRow.after(tblClone);
        $("#btnDelete").hide();
    };
    function DeleteSaleOrderRow(btnDelete) {
        $(btnDelete).closest("tr").remove();
        CalculateSubTotal();
    }
    function ResetCustomerDetails() {
        $("#txtCustomerName").val('');
        $("#txtAddessCus").val('');
        $("#txtOrderNumber").val('');
        $("#txtTotal").val('');
        var tblBody = $("#tblSaleOrderDetails").find("tbody");
        tblBody.find('tr:gt(0)').remove();

        tblBody.find("tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("input[type=text]").val('');
        });
    }
    function CalculateSubTotal() {
        var Total = 0.0;
        var tblBody = $("#tblSaleOrderDetails").find("tbody");
        tblBody.find("tr").each(function () {
            var Quantity = $(this).find("td:eq(1) input[type=text]").val(); 
            var UnitPrice = $(this).find("td:eq(2) input[type=text]").val(); 
            var Discount = $(this).find("td:eq(3) input[type=text]").val();
            var SubTotal = (Quantity * UnitPrice) - Discount;
            Total = Total + SubTotal;
            $(this).find("td:eq(4) input[type=text]").val(SubTotal)
            $("#txtTotal").val(Total);
        });
    }
    function SaveOrderDetails() {
        ListOfSaleOrderDetail = [];
        var tblBody = $("#tblSaleOrderDetails").find("tbody");
        tblBody.find("tr").each(function () {
            var ItemName = $(this).find("td:eq(1) input[type=text]").val();
            var Quantity = $(this).find("td:eq(2) input[type=text]").val();
            var UnitPrice = $(this).find("td:eq(3) input[type=text]").val();
            var Discount = $(this).find("td:eq(4) input[type=text]").val();
            var SubTotal = (Quantity * UnitPrice) - Discount;
            ListOfSaleOrderDetail.push({
                "ItemName": ItemName,
                "Quantity": Quantity,
                "UnitPrice": UnitPrice,
                "Discount": Discount,
                "SubTotal": SubTotal,
            });

        });
        SaleOrderViewModel = {
            "OrderNumber": $("#txtOrderNumber").val(),
            "CustomerName": $("#txtCustomerName").val(),
            "AddressCus": $("#txtAddressCus").val(),
            "ListOfSaleOrderDetail": ListOfSaleOrderDetail
        };
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: '/MasterDetail/Index',
            data: JSON.stringify(SaleOrderViewModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    alert(data.Message);
                    ResetCustomerDetails()
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.Message);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("loi");
            }
        });
    }
</script>


The easiest solution would be to let the SQL Server database in the background handle this internally, by using an INT IDENTITY column as primary key - or a database SEQUENCE object to hand out proper ID values.

What are you using for UserManageEntities?   Could be that it's caching values so the ID hasn't been "saved" yet when you attempt to retrieve it with the .Single() call
